# Can I connect two subnets with the same openVPN on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, openvpn, subnet, vpc

Currently, I have a VPC where I have 3 subnets. In one of them I have a machine with open VPN, through which I access the rest of the machines in the same subnet. I would like to know if it is possible to connect somehow to the other subnets through the vpn that I have already set up in a subnet. Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you could, but way? What's the advantage of doing that?

Comment: OpenVPN in routed or in bridged mode?